# How would the Ramchal's standards for joking about Torah apply to Purim Torah?

Tags: purim, kavod, ramchal

The PTIJ posts (and Purim Torah in general) *seem* to make a mockery of the Torah.

Is there something I'm missing?
Is there some Halacha or words of Razal that allow this?

I am looking at this question primarily through the lens of the Ramchal. He states (Derech Hashem 4:2) in regards to the reverential attitude one ought have during the study of Torah that:

> ונכלל בזה שלא ישב בקלות ראש ולא ינהג שום מנהג ביזיון לא בדבריה ולא
> בספריה וידע לפני מי עומד ומתעסק
>
> included in this is that he should not sit with light-headedness nor
> act in any disrespectful manner - neither towards its words nor
> towards its books and cognize before whom one stands and is involved
> with (i.e. God)

How would his standards apply here to "Purim Torah"?

Comment: this should be migrated to Meta (IMHO)

Comment: @rosends this should be migrated to ptij

Comment: How do I migrate this to Meta? I dont mean this as a joke

Comment: I think this should stay here, not meta. It's a perfectly fine question on Judaism

Comment: Rabbah always began his lectures with a joke "and the scholars were cheered.  After that, he sat in awe and began the lecture."  [Shabbat 30b]. Was he wrong in mixing jokes and holy Torah study?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi define what his "jokes" were. How do you know they were comparable to Purim Torah?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi The Pnei Yehoshua in his introduction says that he was not making mere jokes, ch"v.

Comment: I have edited the Question to make it a nonduplicate

Comment: Before asking how the Ramchal's standards for joking about Torah apply to Purim Torah (on this site), you should clarify what those relevant standards are. You don't bring them, and don't seem to know what they are. Maybe start with asking (in a different question?) what the Ramchal's standards for joking about Torah are (knowing he says something about קלות ראש שבקדושה).

Comment: The (currently) first 3 sentences look like a rant. and should probably be removed The first actual question(s) seem to be covered by the linked question, this is marked as duplicate of, and could be removed as well. That done, you should probably edit what remains, to better reflect what you know about what the Ramchal says (and where you know it from), and why you think it might apply to Purim Torah (on this site).

Comment: I summarized the rant into 1 sentence

Comment: I'd like to understand why the question is about Purim Torah _on this site_. This site didn't invent Purim Torah, it's a long tradition among great talmidei chachamim: it seems that Purim is different. It might be a good start to find out if the Ramchal opposed Purim Torah in general, or perhaps wrote some himself!

Comment: @MichoelR good points. I've edited zunior's question to make it applicable to both this site and more generically to Purim Torah. If he takes issue, he can rollback the edit.